# Putting another field on event location record

Tags: civievent

I have information about the capacity of venues that I would like to store. Venues currently are only being stored as locations on event records. Is there a way to add an extra field to locations on events?

I have seen this ticket but what I am looking for is much simpler [Using contacts as event locations](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/230/using-contacts-as-event-locations)

Answer (score 1):

One workaround approach would be to make an event template for each location that includes the venue size. This won't work if you are already using templates in other ways and need to mix eg luncheon template with different venues.

Comment: Thanks but that won't be suitable for our situation as we are already using event templates for different kinds of events that we are running and there will be a lot of different venues.